# how can i translate strings in search page result?

Tags: string-overrides

On Drupal 8, how can i translate these strings in search page result :

```
Your search yielded no results

Enter your keywords

Search

Search results
```

I can do it with jQuery but i know it is not a good approach (even if it works)   :

```
$('.my-theme-search-page h2').text("Résultats de la recherche");
```

Comment: Yes, this definitely will not do it (jQuery).  Have you perused https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/multilingual/translating-site-interfaces ?

Comment: yes, the strings are all in `admin/config/regional/translate`, but if you load the language from the drupal translation server they should be translated already